# Methods to avoiding cross-product APOC query (using hashmap?)?

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

I currently have a `Neo4J` database with a simple data structure comprised of about 400 million `(:Node {id:String, refs:List[String]})`, with two properties: An `id`, which is a string, and `refs`, which is a list of strings.

I need to search all of these nodes to identify relationships between them. These directed relationships exist if a node's `id` is in the `ref` list of another nose. A simple query that accomplishes what I want (but is too slow):

```
MATCH (a:Node), (b:Node) 
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b) AND a.id IN b.refs
CREATE (b)-[:CITES]->(a)
```

I can use `apoc.periodic.iterate`, but the query is still much too slow:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (a:Node), (b:Node) 
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b) 
AND a.id IN b.refs RETURN a, b",
"CREATE (b)-[:CITES]->(a)",
{batchSize:10000, parallel:false,iterateList:true})
```

Any suggestions as to how I can build this database and relationships efficiently? I've vague thoughts about creating a hash table as I first add the Nodes to the database, but am not sure how to implement this, especially in Neo4j.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first create an index on `:Node(id)`, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Node(id);
```

then this query should be able to take advantage of the index to quickly find each `a` node:

```
MATCH (b:Node)
UNWIND b.refs AS ref
MATCH (a:Node)
WHERE a.id = ref
CREATE (b)-[:CITES]->(a);
```

Currently, the Cypher execution planner does not support using the index when **directly** comparing the values of 2 properties. In the above query, the `WHERE` clause is comparing a property with a variable, so the index can be used.

*The `ID(a) < ID(b)` test was omitted, since your question did not state that ordering the native node IDs in such a way was required.*

[UPDATE 1]

If you want to run the creation step in parallel, try this usage of the APOC procedure [apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate):

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (b:Node) UNWIND b.refs AS ref RETURN b, ref",
  "MATCH (a:Node {id: ref}) CREATE (b)-[:CITES]->(a)",
  {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

The first Cypher statement passed to the procedure just returns each `b`/`ref` pair. The second statement (which is run in parallel) uses the index to find the `a` node and creates the relationship. This division of effort puts the more expensive processing in the statement running in a parallel thread. The `iterateList: true` option is omitted, since we (probably) want the second statement to run in parallel for each `b`/`ref` pair.

[UPDATE 2]

You can encounter deadlock errors if parallel executions try to add relationships to the same nodes (since each parallel transaction will attempt to write-lock every new relationship's end nodes). To avoid deadlocks involving just the `b` nodes, you can do something like this to ensure that a `b` node is not processed in parallel:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (b:Node) RETURN b",
  "UNWIND b.refs AS ref MATCH (a:Node {id: ref}) CREATE (b)-[:CITES]->(a)",
  {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

However, this approach is still vulnerable to deadlocks if parallel executions can try to write-lock the same `a` nodes (or if any `b` nodes can also be used as `a` nodes). But at least hopefully this addendum will help you to understand the problem.

[UPDATE 3]

Since these deadlocks are race conditions that depend on multiple parallel executions trying to lock the same nodes at the same time, you might be able to work around this issue by retrying the "inner statement" whenever it fails. And you could also try making the batch size smaller, to reduce the probability that multiple parallel retries will overlap in time. Something like this:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (b:Node) RETURN b",
  "UNWIND b.refs AS ref MATCH (a:Node {id: ref}) CREATE (b)-[:CITES]->(a)",
  {batchSize: 1000, parallel: true, retries: 100})
```

Comment: Thank you, @cybersam. Very helpful. 

I added the `ID(a) < ID(b)` simply to avoid iterating over all pairs. I was thinking that without that constraint, each pair would be visited twice (once as `a,b` and once as `b,a`). 

I sit correct to say that, if I have `n` nodes, this complexity moves from $O(n*n)$ to O(n)$ (i.e. I am only visiting every node, not every pair of nodes)?

Comment: Also, @cybersam, would it be advantageous to execute this via `apoc.periodic.iterate`, and if so can I use `parallel:true`, as in the query below?

    ```CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "MATCH (b:Node) 
    UNWIND b.refs AS ref 
    MATCH (a:Node) 
    WHERE a.id = ref
    RETURN a, b",
   "CREATE (b)-[:CITES]->(a)",
    {batchSize:10000, parallel:true,iterateList:true});```

Comment: Since your use case requires `CITES` to point in a specific direction, the `ID(a) < ID(b)` test would prevent the creation of some desired relationships.

Comment: See my updated answer for a suggestion for how to use `apoc.periodic.iterate`.

Comment: This has all been very helpful. However, when I run this in parallel, I end up with a large percentage of failures. These failures disappear when I set `parallel:false`, but then the process takes a very long time (I've also replaced `CREATE` with `MERGE` to avoid duplicate relationships). Any suggestions as to how I can run this in parallel while avoiding failures?

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you. Unfortunately all `b` nodes can also be used as `a` nodes, so I cannot use `parallel:true` without significant problems. Is there anything else I can do to speed this query up (as it is still taking many hours-to-days for ~160M nodes)?